# Finding IAM SA Keys Older than 89 Days in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-iam

I'm trying to write a script that will hunt out all IAM service keys that have existed longer than 89 days to meet our security requirements, but I'm typing myself into knots.

My best attempt so far:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys list --quiet --managed-by=user --iam-account $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL --filter='createTime<=P89D' --format='csv[no-heading](KEY_ID)'
```

But this appears to catch all of the keys. I'm struggling to get my head around Google's filter configurations. Any pointers gladly accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying REST method is [projects.serviceAccounts.keys.list](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts.keys/list) and the result is a [ServiceAccountKey](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts.keys#ServiceAccountKey) which contains `valid[Before|After]Time` which are strings in the protobuf [Timestamp](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Timestamp).

So, I think this needs to either be a string comparison of dates (!) or comparing durations (but I'm unfamiliar with the duration format and how to compare).

You can convert the `validAfterTime` to a duration, i.e. `--filter=validAfterTime.duration()` (see [`duration`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/projections#duration)) and then compare (!) but as Durations

Or construct a date that's within your scope and compare as-is. The following is *hacky*, please proceed with caution:

```sh
PROJECT=...
ACCOUNT=...

PAST=$(date -d "-90 days" +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ)

EMAIL="${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

gcloud iam service-accounts keys list \
--iam-account=${EMAIL} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--filter="validAfterTime<${PAST}"
```

I think there's a better way to do this!

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up using the above method with ISO dates generated in a script and it seems to be working now. It feels like the kind of thing that should be nicely handled with the filters, but getting it working is taking more time than a `bash date`

Comment: Your answer by itself is a **comment** and not an answer as it does not provide a solution. Instead, you should select the answer and post a comment to the answer instead of posting another answer.